# Shopify AJAX request returns 404 in Theme Customizer, but gives 200 on frontend

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I have a Shopify theme that generates data using a template file. That file looks like this:

`blog.ajax.liquid`

```
{% layout none %}
{% assign real_item_count = 0 %}

{% capture results %}
  {% for article in blog.articles %}
    {% assign real_item_count = real_item_count | plus: 1  %}

    {% capture blog_html %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading{{forloop.index}}">
          <h5 class="accordion_header">
            <a href="#collapse{{forloop.index}}" class="card-header__title {% if forloop.index != 1 %}collapsed{% endif %}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="{% if forloop.index == 1 %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}" aria-controls="collapse{{forloop.index}}">
              <p class="faq-container__accordion-question">{{ article.title }}</p>
              <span class="card-header__title-icon"><span class="card-header__title-icon-trigger"></span></span>
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{forloop.index}}" class="collapse {% if forloop.index == 1 %}show{% endif %}" aria-labelledby="heading{{forloop.index}}" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body p1">
            {{ article.content }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endcapture %}

    {
      "blog_html": {{ blog_html | escape | json }}
    }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}


{
  "result_count": {{ real_item_count }},
  "results": [{{ results }}]
}
```

The AJAX call is structured like this:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: '/blogs/faqs/tagged/' + category.getAttribute('data-category'),
        data: {
          view: 'ajax'
        },
        dataType: 'json'
      })
      .done((data) => {
        let resultHtml = '';
        data.results.forEach((product) => {
          resultHtml += product.blog_html;
        });
        $(selectors.accordion).html(this.stripHtml(resultHtml));
      })
      .fail((jqXHR, textStatus, data) => {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText));
        console.log('Error');
      });
```

On the frontend, the code is working, XHR request returns `200` however within the theme customizer, the AJAX request above will always return `404 not found`, this one has stumped us as to why the code isn't working in the Theme Customizer, but works on the frontend. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to check the URL and make sure it form the right URL in both cases.

Comment: @onkar yes for sure, it was the first thing I checked, they are both the same

Comment: I think you need to check it also in this way `url: '/blogs/faqs/tagged/' + category.getAttribute('data-category')?view='ajax'`, it specify the template name as well into AJAX call. might be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks @onkar, can confirm I tried that before posting here, I will edit my question so it's not ambiguous